# near-api-js does not return contract method response

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm working on testnet with using near-api-js (Nextjs) to call contract method.
When I call the method without Approve Transaction (No deposit or Call from the contract was deployed by current account), near-api-js return the result of contract method but when I call from another Near Account (It require to change to wallet screen to approve transaction), near-api-js will return the transactionHash. I used this transactionHash to check on Explorer and got the result is my contract still return the correct result but it seems not to send this result to my client.
Anyone can tell me what happened and how to resolve it?

Here is my sample transactionHash: 8NHCjNkM6VDnSyMg43gzwngNPNZJTDCnvDSTtQj5QsM
There is no problem when call method from near-cli or near-api-js without deposit option.
Below is my code on front-end

```js
contract?.init_new_event?.(
    {
     title: event_name,
     location: 'Hanoi',
     description: des,
     privacy: [],
     cover_image: rootCid,
     type: parseInt(event_type),
     start_date,
     end_date,
    },
    100000000000000,
    depositAmount,
    ).then((res) => {
     if (res) {
      router.push(`/event/event-detail?id=${res}`);
     } else {
      onShowResult({
       type: 'error',
       msg: 'Creat event failure',
      });
     }
    }).catch((err) => {
     onShowResult({
      type: 'error',
      msg: String(err),
     });
   });
```

And when I call from owner account of this contract, I received a response like

```js
"nMX4ZeyxLTK9ZYyJmA9FhR7Y8zgieLsvnc9VeJhGtRVsAm82tnzMG"
```

But when call from another account, I just received transactionHash such as

```
transactionHashes=EgSmzhmtMHr6WNmtLpJaa7W9qLn6PzdHEzK2ST13vGgA
```

You can see on near explorer, the contract method still working correctly:
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/BQVMve8FtgQ8sqBDyzS3FrTR5buYy4qmuCWcCVD7K8KE

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what your problem is. Could you add your code where you use and call the contract method (on your front-end)? Can you write what the desired result is, and what you currently get?

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your reply, I updated my question, hope that can help you easier to understand my problem. ty

Comment: Thank you for adding the code as well. I'm still not sure I understand. The desired response look awfully similar to the transactionHashes response. The only difference I see is that the desired response doesn't have the word "ransactionHashes" In it. Please elaborate on this sentence ("I used this transactionHash to check on Explorer and got the result is my contract still return the correct result but it seems not to send this result to my client"). What is the explorer showing that you aren't able to see on the client?

Answer (score 0):

When you call api (attach deposit) you can only check txHash to know tx success or not,  you can't check response from smart contract.
=> The solution : Separate deposit api from your main-action api, user must deposit before call main api then you can get response on main-action normally